# Google Analytics and measuring search terms to destination pages

Tags: google-analytics

Been using internal site search with Google Analytics and while I love the ability to see what my users are searching for, I am having a really hard time figuring out what search terms lead to which pages.

When I search on both the `nextPagePath` and `searchKeyword` dimensions while filtering on the search results page at the current path, the `nextPagePath` is always the search results page even when I know it shouldn't be (when tracking my own obscure searches). The same goes for using the `searchDestinationPage` dimension. I can't get any data that shows a jump from a search results page to another page on the site.

Here's a cleaned up example of my api query.

`dimensions=ga:searchKeyword,ga:nextPagePath&metrics=ga:pageviews&filters=ga:previousPagePath=@dosearch`

When I use the standard Analytics UI and look at the Destination Pages list under Content->Site Search->Destination pages, I only have 25 or so, all of which are just the variations on the base search-result page URL.

Do I need additional tracking code on my search results pages? Custom variables? A different query through the API?

I can see the tracking requests going out from both the search results and the pages selected from the results.

I found a couple of questions in the Analytics forums that ask this same question, but none of them had anything resembling a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet you are not using the proper dimensions in the API

See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/internalsearch

ga:searchDestinationPage is probably what you wanted when using ga:nextPagePath

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. It seems that if I want to include ga:searchKeyword, I'll never be able to retrieve any kind of page path that doesn't reference dosearch. If I drop ga:searchKeyword, I can get ga:previousPagePath with a filter for the search URL and ga:nextPagePath without it, but then I have to parse the URL in the prevPagePath to extract the search keywords. I guess that's my only option. I'm already doing a lot of data massaging to convert search keywords into something measureable, so what's a little more effort there?